# What is this possible old coin found in Western Ukraine?

Tags: numismatics

I think, at early eighties, when I was a child, I found this “coin” in my room, at the second floor of a standard Soviet building in Lviv, a city at the west of Ukraine. The house was build, as far as I know, in 1963.

[image]
[image]

Images in a resolution 600 DPI are [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtV3o.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjibA.jpg).

The diameter is 2 cm.

I don’t know what is it and how it occurred in my room.

I have not seen any symbol or emblem strongly resembling that on the “coin” on other coins or medals before or later, so I do not offer anything to compare this to.

But I wish to identify this historical thing, before I shall pass into history myself.

Comment: The lack of any identifying text for country and value indicate to me that your coin is actually a token or commemorative medal - possibly political in nature (the eagle carrying what appears to be a lion may be indicative of a political victory). The P and N could be initials of a political party. From an artistic point of view, I'd say it looks early 20th century - maybe up to the 1930s..

Comment: Welcome to HistorySE, Alex Ravsky! Please remove the distracting para 1, and adjust the next accordingly, we just don't do 'paranormal' here and hence this is only distracting. What we would need: what are these "in other sources"?!? You have different pictures of 'this type' of object? Those we need to see or pointed at.

Comment: @LаngLаngС By the other sources I mean emblems which I saw in my life, mainly coats of arms on coins. During last centuries Lviv belonged to different countries (Poland, Austria, Austria-Hungary, Russia, Germany) which had eagle-like birds at their coats of arms. I saw a lot of them, of various shapes and from different times. But none of them was very similar to the emblem at the image.

Comment: Possibly related [P. N. in Lviv](https://shadowsofaforgottenworld.blogspot.com/2014/12/benchmark-on-lvivs-city-hall.html).